# FFMPEG Raspberry Pi to Facebook Live Stream

Tags: pi-2, ffmpeg, raspivid

So I've been streaming video to YouTube just fine with the below command.  I then wanted to do the same thing with Facebook on my page, and I get a strange Authorization error.  On the Facebook side, my video just never previews at all, and says:

[image]

Here's the code I'm using on the RPi w/FFMPEG, keep in mind this exact same code works fine on YouTube and streams easily (without the auth key).

```
cd /opt/vc/bin/ && sudo /opt/vc/bin/raspivid -o - -t 0 -fps 30 -h 720 -w 1280 -b 4000000 -rot 270 -vs | /root/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -re -ar 44100 -ac 2 -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ac 2 -i /dev/zero -f h264 -i - -vcodec copy -acodec aac -ab 128k -g 120 -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/*YOUR KEY HERE*
```

Answer (score 2):

try to quote target url:

```
cd /opt/vc/bin/ && sudo /opt/vc/bin/raspivid -o - -t 0 -fps 30 -h 720 -w 1280 -b 4000000 -rot 270 -vs | /root/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -re -ar 44100 -ac 2 -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ac 2 -i /dev/zero -f h264 -i - -vcodec copy -acodec aac -ab 128k -g 120 -strict experimental -f flv "rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/*YOUR KEY HERE*"
```